# Replace the text area used to answer a question with a "Add your answer" button for users with a reputation of 1

Tags: feature-request, answers, new-users

Recently, I noticed that the number of users with a reputation of 1 who writes as answer a request for more information (mostly related to their Drupal site), or a completely different question became higher, in the past days.

It doesn't probably help the fact they don't see an "add comment" link, and they see a text area where they can start writing.

I would propose to (for users with a reputation lower than 20):

- Hide the text area for answering a question
- Show a "Add your answer" button.

This is similar to what it is done for questions, when users are watching their own questions: The text area for the answer is not visible, and a "Answer Your Question" button, or "Add Another Answer" button is instead shown.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I am asking this feature request here because I think it is a situation very specific for *Drupal Answers*. It is probably a situation common to other Stack Exchange sites with similar traffic, but it is not a situation generally found in all the Stack Exchange sites.

I asked [Show the "add comment" link also to users who cannot add comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144537/show-the-add-comment-link-also-to-users-who-cannot-add-comments) on *Meta Stack Overflow*; this is a (someway) follow-up to that question.